# UITableViewController in UITabBar

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I'm trying to create a UITabBarController around my UITableView Controller. I'm using this code. But the problem is that when this is used the Navigation Bar disappears. How do I work around this?

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
StyledTableViewController *viewController1 = [[StyledTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StyledTableViewController" bundle:nil];

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add UINavigationController to Navigation Bar plus it matain your hierarchy of views

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
StyledTableViewController *viewController1 = [[StyledTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StyledTableViewController" bundle:nil];
 UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController1];

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Comment: Ahh, I see simple solution. Thanks.